# Offering a fallback on Applet Security Exception

Tags: java, security, applet, securityexception, next-generation-plugin

I have an Applet that is required to run with some privileges, meaning a warning message will be displayed when it loads. If the user denies the warning message I would like to redirect to an error page and explain what happened. Is there any way to do this?

I looked in to having a timer running and redirect after a certain time period but that's not that exact and it would be nice to catch the response from the pop-up instead.

The following exception is thrown if the user denies the warning:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: attempted to open sandboxed jar [jar-file] 
    as a Trusted-Library
```

The exception is thrown before reaching the init function.

Comment: `catch` the `SecurityException` and call the code to display your error page from there.

Comment: The exception is thrown before execution reaches the applet init function.

Comment: how is the warning message generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I looked in to having a timer running and redirect after a certain time period ..

..extend that to add a JS function that cancels the timer, then call that JS from the applet, is about the best protection you can get.

A try/catch on security related matters can work for some JREs that load applet sand-boxed if the security prompt is refused, but other run-times (notably the [Iced Tea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5356850/418556) JRE) will not load the applet at all if the security prompt is refused.

> I have an Applet that is required to run with some privileges.. Basically we store a file there, the file can be any file and the size can therefore be any value. The user will choose this file themselves and they can choose anything from a 1kb textfile to a many-gigabyte movie. ..

If the user can be guaranteed to have a 'Next Generation' - Plug-In 2 JRE (mentioned in the [applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info)), it is possible to the use the JNLP API in an embedded applet.  The JNLP services provide access to the local disks for a sand-boxed app.  See this [demo of the JNLP file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

But there is a slight hitch.  There is no option to persist the **path** to the file chosen by the user.  In this lesser security environment, the JRE does not provide a `File` but instead a JNLP API `FileContents` object.  It will not provide a path and is not serializable.  But if the user is willing to choose the file each run, it could be workable.

---

..and that reminds me.  Perhaps a better alternative for launching trusted apps. is to offer a free-floating (applet or) frame using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  If the user refuses, it never appears on-screen, but they can click the launch button again any time they like (to be prompted again).

Comment: We need to store a persistent file on the users filesystem.

Comment: What is in the file?  How much spaces is it expected to take?  What is it for?

Comment: It's impossible to say anything about the size, it is largely dependent on the specific case.

Comment: <DWS>Well gee, if you can vague that up a little for me, I can provide a complete answer.</DWS>

Comment: Basically we store a file there, the file can be any file and the size can therefore be any value. The user will choose this file themselves and they can choose anything from a 1kb textfile to a many-gigabyte movie. We need to store this file over multiple sessions and we can't do it server-side. In the future it's possible we will use HTML5 to do this, but we can't rely on that just yet.